# dotnet command for creating startup project

Tags: asp.net, .net, command-line-interface, blazor

I want know what is the command line for making a directory a startup project.

I have 2 directories inside EmployeeManagement and on sln file:

1. Models
2. Web
3. Employeemanagement.sln

Now instead of Right clicking and making Web the startup project, is there a way of doing it using command line interface.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There are the .net CLI commands : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new

Comment: I've already used following commands for adding project to solution file.
1.  dotnet sln EmployeeManagement.sln add Web
2.  dotnet add Web reference Models 
3.  dotnet add Web reference Models

But If I run dotnet run command, it says "Coudn't file Project file to run.....". So how do I make Web project the default project?

Comment: Navigate to your Web project folder where the csproj file is located. Run you dotnet commands here. For example if you run the `dotnet run` command here it will try to run the .csproj file you are currenlty in. Other notable commands are `dontet watch run`, `dotnet test`, `dotnet build`, `dotnet publish`.
The 'set as startup' is a Visual Studio feature. Not a command line command. That just something that VS keeps track for you.

Answer (score 1):

In the .Net 5.0, you can do: dotnet run --project  , everytime you need to run the project.

CLI Example:

dotnet run --project Web/Web.csproj